# Fragment se muestra superpuesto en una Activity

Tags: android-studio

No termino con un problema porque todos se quedan sin resolver, y ahora me encuentro con otro, que no me explico porque está pasando, ya que he visto otros códigos y funciona correctamente.

El problema es que tengo puesto un botón en una clase que extiende de **AppCompatActivity**, para llamar desde ese botón a una clase que extiende de **Fragment**, al pulsar el botón se muestran superpuestas el `Fragment` viéndose las dos.

Este es uno de los códigos que he probado y tengo puesto en el `Activity` para mostrar el Fragment

**Alarmas.java**

`public class Alarmas_Login extends AppCompatActivity`

Codigo para mostrar el Fragment

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container_login, new Alarmas());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

**alarmas_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Alarmas_Login">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/intro_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Introducir Contraseña"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_aceptar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="Aceptar"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/intro_login" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</FrameLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Agradecería vuestra ayuda si alguien me puede decir como mostrar solo una clase.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola de nuevo Jorgesys, ya he puesto el codigo xml, y no se si tiene que ver algo como esta puesto el codigo en el xml, pero otro mal comportamiento que tiene cuando se muestra tanto la activity como el fragment es que se muestra encima del menú tapándolo, no se queda dentro del FrameLayout

Comment: un poco extraño lo que comentas,tienes de casualidad tu ejemplo en github?

Comment: Podría darle un vistazo @SoCu

Comment: Me daba fallos y no conseguía subirlo, pero aquí lo tienes https://github.com/SoCu/Prueba.git veras que en el menú **Menu 1** muestra el pdf que esta en una clase Activity y _tapa el TabLayout_ en el menú **Boton** es una clase diferente Fragment y también _tapa el TabLayout_ en el menú **VesEsta**se porque narices _sale primero lo que tengo puesto en el menú Alarmas_, una vez que quitas esa pantalla pulsa el botón **Linea 1** luego en **S Ga** y se muestra el _contenido doble_, si pulsas en **Linea 2** y luego en **S Vi** se muestra pero _tapando el TabLayout_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El Framelayout container_login existe, el problema es que este elemento no tiene definidas "constraints" de posición

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Alarmas_Login">

...
...

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </FrameLayout>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

debes agregarlas, por ejemplo:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_aceptar">
    </FrameLayout>
```

Te sugiero quitar  transaction.addToBackStack(null);

[addToBackStack()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack(java.lang.String))
Agrega la transacción a el "Back stack". Esto significa que la transacción se recordará después de que se confirme, y revertirá su operación cuando se saque de la pila.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container_login, new Alarmas());
//transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Pero ese codigo es el que ha puesto Roimer, y sigue dando el mismo problema

Comment: Elimina también transaction.addToBackStack(null) @SoCu

Comment: Eliminando esa linea sigue el mismo comportamiento, pide un contraseña para mostrar el Fragment y lo muestra, pero junto con el activity donde introduzco la contraseña y el boton.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás usando un `ContraintLayout`, pero el `FrameLayout` hijo no tiene las restricciones correctas: dice que ocupará todo el espacio disponible sin restricciones (es decir, toda la pantalla).

**Solución**: colócale las restricciones al `FrameLayout`; por ejemplo:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_aceptar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hola Roimer, así es ocupa toda la pantalla, he puesto esas restricciones que pones y sigue pasando lo mismo, y se siguen viendo las dos pantallas justas.